# Nest complementary objects quick, without having to deform,distort?

Tags: mesh, transforms

[image]

These are just simple placeholders for any two complementary objects which would have many vertices placed in the same location.

To get this picture I had to distort the tetrahedron and pull each of its' vertices to the vertices of the cube, by moving the cursor from vertice to vertice, and go into Edit mode of the tetrahedron to actually move its' vertices one at a time.

Is it possible to achieve the same result without distortion along the way, and in less steps ?

I already posed a similar question which was answered, but wasn't general enough, because the objects had a common axis, which made the alignment rely solely on Rotation... while simultaneous Scaling AND Rotation is required in most cases.

Comment: Is this question about _creating_ the complementary objects, or transforming them once they exist?

Comment: Transforming once they exist, though I'd take the creation explanation on the side too, if it doesn't require manual connection of the vertices, that is, only selection and then connection in one go/click.

Comment: The only way I can think of creating the objects is to construct them from edges.. probably not what you want.. but I'll post anyway, and refer you to another answer about transformation.

Comment: say if I wanted to animate the tetrahedron coming from a random direction on a random path, how would I get it to "land" in the cube so perfectly ? XD Don't tell me it's not possible, or even worse that nobody is thinking about these simple possibilities.  One cheat would be to run an animation in reverse, but i don't want cheats. I hope I'm just uninformed.

Comment: I've been in stop-motion animation most of my life, and keying in reverse ain't cheating, in my book of rules!  :D I'll try making a gif when I've got time..

Comment: I've popped in a gif.

Comment: You've linked your own answer to  MY question I was referring to being answered XD NICE, but as I've said in the previous reply, the method doesn't fit the bill.   Three steps, 1. align one vertex using the cursor and pulling the whole form (as is already happening with shown) 2. align a second vertex in a similar way but preserving the form, so that in the 3. step only Rotation remains to align the 3rd vertex.

Comment: Basically the Scaling has to happen in direct relation to the distance between the first two vertices (of the cube)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95202/discussion-between-robin-betts-and-t8ja).

Answer (score 1):

To construct the dual object, you can:

- <kbd>X</kbd> Delete > 'Faces Only' of the original
- <kbd>F</kbd> between selected vertices to create new edges
- <kbd>F</kbd> selected edges to create new faces

[image]

If you already have the complementary objects, not in the right orientation or scale, maybe [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118903/35559) will help?

EDIT: following commentary .. this sequence was keyed manually, forward and in reverse from a static exact fit position. I personally think 'cheating' is the easiest approach.

[image]

Comment: I found a way using https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html?highlight=align%20transform%20orientation       Ctrl+Shift+Space to "sample" the orientation system  (Shift+Space) of the cubes vertex in Edit mode, and then select the thetrahedron and go into object>transform>align to transform orientation, which aligns one axis of the tetra to the axis of the cube, but there are still too many steps and I'm basically back to the situation I already described had been answered.

Comment: @t8ja  Custom Transform Orientations  work on edges and faces, too, absolutely one of the most useful tools in modeling,, I'm very surprised they've lost the standard shortcut for it in 2.8, where you have to make your own,